# How to print a jasper report in 3 exemplar with little changes?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I've created a jasper report with iReport and I can print it perfectly.
I need to print 3 examples of it (original example, client example, department example) with very few changes, for example changing a label in the report.

I pass `PRINT_FOR` as parameter to  iReport.

**Does any body know how to approach this goal?**

```
HashMap parameters = new HashMap();
String option = "C:\\option.jasper";
JRDataSource beanDataSource = reportMapper.getDataSource();
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(option, parameters, beanDataSource);
JasperPrintManager.printPage(jasperPrint, 0, true))
```

Answer (score 2):

A first thought is just make a general report template and have some "hooks" in which you can insert the differences for each version; you can send the "differences" via the parameters from Java.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `Static Text` field you can use a `Text Field` that allows you to use and expression to determine the text output. In this case you would check to see if the `PRINT_FOR` parameter is equal to the client or department and if not use the original value. You expression would look something like this:

```
($P{PRINT_FOR}.equals("DEPARTMENT") ? "Department Label" : ($P{PRINT_FOR}.equals("CLIENT") ? "Client Label" : "Original Label"))
```

Where `Department Label` is outputted when `PRINT_FOR` is equal to `DEPARMTNENT`, `Client Label` is outputted when `PRINT_FOR` is equal to `Client`, and `Original Label` is outputted if it is not equal to either of the above.

Also worth noting is that in the code snippet about you never set the value for the `PRINT_FOR` parameter in your java code and you are not using a generic `HashMap`. It should look something closer to:

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameters.put("PRINT_FOR", "CLIENT");
```

---

**UPDATE:** Based on your comment, you basically want to do export all 3 reports as one at the same time. This can be accomplised by using the [`JRPrintServiceExporter`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRPrintServiceExporter.html). Basically create the three `JasperPrint` Objects, and put them in a list. Then use the exporter to print them out. Something like:

```
//add all three JasperPrints to the list below
List<JasperPrint> jasperPrints = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();

...

//create an exporter
JRExporter exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();
//add the JasperPrints to the exporter via the JASPER_PRINT_LIST param
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jasperPrints);
exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PAGE_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.TRUE);
//this one makes it so that the settings choosen in the first dialog will be applied to the
//other documents in the list also
exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG_ONLY_ONCE, Boolean.TRUE);

exporter.exportReport();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This code just prints me one example every time. what i want is to print 3 exemplar every time user clicks on the print button in my application.

Comment: @itro Sorry I did not update sooner, I just didn't have a chance to type anything up before now. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you use your own JRBeanCollectionDataSource, you must create for each JasperPrint their respective JRBeanCollectionDataSource

```
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource dsCliente = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listaDetalle);
        JasperPrint jasperPrintCliente = JasperFillManager.fillReport("plantillaDoc.jasper", paramsHojaCliente, dsCliente);
        listaJasperPrint.add(jasperPrintCliente);

        JRBeanCollectionDataSource dsCaja1 = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listaDetalle);
        JasperPrint jasperPrintCaja1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport("plantillaDoc.jasper", paramsHojaCaja, dsCaja1);
        listaJasperPrint.add(jasperPrintCaja1);
```