# How to create two pages in report with same content

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I need to duplicate the first page and create two pages in the *JasperReports* report. The current code look like this.

```
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(inputStream);
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, beanColDataSource);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile("test.pdf");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print a jasper report in 3 exemplar with little changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916025/how-to-print-a-jasper-report-in-3-exemplar-with-little-changes) and [Additional page for Jasper reports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20376058/876298)

Comment: @AlexK Since there is no answers accepted or useful i asked this

Comment: The advice of using `JASPER_PRINT_LIST` is useful in your case. This both posts are relevant to your question.